# Why different results from Java and SQLite studio for the same query?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am getting different results for the same query when I run from Java program and  SQLite studio.

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Do you have any idea?

In java I am using the below code:

```
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
 Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db.db3"); 
 Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
 ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

**Query:**

```
select creation_time as 'Task creation date',
sum(case when working_hrs <= 5.0 then 1 else 0 end) as '0-5 hours',
sum(case when working_hrs between 5.1 and 10.0 then 1 else 0 end ) as '5-10 hours',
sum(case when working_hrs between 10.1 and 15.0 then 1 else 0 end ) as '10-15 hours',
sum(case when working_hrs between 15.1 and 20.0 then 1 else 0 end ) as '15-20 hours'
from (select task_id, strftime('%d-%m-%Y',datetime(creation_timestamp/1000,'unixepoch','localtime')) as creation_time,
round((end_timestamp/1000 - creation_timestamp/1000) / 3600.0, 2) as working_hrs  from tasks order by creation_timestamp desc
 ) group by creation_time
```

**Result screenshot from java:**
[image]

**Result screenshot from SQLite:**[image]

[Edit 1] Sample data added
**Sample data:**

```
"task_id"         ,"session_id"         ,"creation_timestamp","start_timestamp","end_timestamp"
"375501182808662" ,"8337010517175324685","1539828105263"     ,"1539828105601"  ,"1539828158217"
"485386198356091" ,"7933542082890916440","1540554061336"     ,"1540576602811"  ,"1540576630640"
"978182458409950" ,"9006702446688652505","1539801529300"     ,"1539810165157"  ,"1539810210255"
"1153933381873910","727803067664621142" ,"1541049927995"     ,"1541056911723"  ,"1541057700285"
"7007028125080279","2997722960661559829","1539635192934"     ,"1539635197122"  ,"1539635280448"
```

Comment: Show the data used to get those results (**not** as an image; as text that can be copied and pasted. A create table and bunch of insert statements would be great)?

Comment: I have added sample data. I can not append actual data here as it spans 1000 of records.

Comment: Then update your example outputs to match the provided sample data (and see earlier comment about how `create table` and `insert` statements would be nice; something that can just be copied and pasted into a sqlite shell to create the table). The idea is to have a complete and reproducible example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Try this and see what sort of results you get: change the `sum` expressions to something like `count(case when … then 1 end) as '…'` (all 4 of them). I simplifies the query a little, and possibly improves its performance as counting is easier than adding. You might also possibly put something on SQLFiddle for testing.

Comment: Removing the 'localtime' modifier gives same results for the query in both java and SQLite Studio. Does any one know why does that work? Hint: adding 'localtime' modifier gives different group by result.